# Set Selected Input Option to variable value

Tags: jquery, html

I have a select Input menu that is created dynamically, This creates a row item. The user can then click the row to edit their selection. I am having a problem setting the default drop down option to a variable. I put a simplified version of my problem in a jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/SteveRobertson/cPtLj/1/

What I am trying to do in the fiddle is have the default option be option3.

I have also tried  using "value" instead of "text" and doing this

```
   $("#selectid option[value='"+cat+"']").prop("selected", "selected");
```

I can not seem to get the value to set. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var text1 = 'your text';
$("select option").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == text1; 
}).prop('selected', true);
```

or use

```
<select id="selectid">
<option value="option1">option1</option>
<option value="option2">option2</option>
<option value="option3">option3</option>
<option value="option4">option4</option>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#selectid").val("option3");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cPtLj/8/)**

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cat = 'option3';
    $("#selectid option:contains(" + cat + ")").prop("selected", true);
});
```

Notes:

- In your jsFiddle, you didn't include jQuery..
- You were using `cat` in your code, as a `string`, not a `variable`.
- In this case, I used `:contains() Selector`.
- The `.prop()` method need `boolean` as its second arguments.

---

References:

- [`:contains() Selector`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) - jQuery API Documentation
- [`:prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) - jQuery API Documentation

---

#### UPDATED

This method is fair enough. It's also works for options like `option11` and `option111`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your string
    var cat = 'option11';

    // get all options
    $("#selectid option")
        // remove all selected
       .prop("selected", false)

       // now filter the one you want
       .filter(function () {
           return $.trim($(this).text()) == cat;
       })
            // select it
           .prop('selected', true);

});
```

- You can check the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cPtLj/18/).

Comment: @PSL Thanks for your comment, I've been noticed at first, but I omitted that. Now I add another solution too, [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cPtLj/18/). :)

Comment: Better +1, No problem. I think OP should go with option value though for a shorter code.

Answer (score 0):

First you haven't included the jQuery library in your fiddle.

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    $("select#selectid").val("option3");
});
```

Check out this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/t5GWr/)